# Does Burp Suite affect my request directly?

Tags: file-upload, burp-suite, file-inclusion

When I try to bypass the security configuration of Natas13 (http://natas13.natas.labs.overthewire.org/  A/P:natas13/lW3jYRI02ZKDBb8VtQBU1f6eDRo6WEj9) while using Burp Suite Community Edition on Windows 10, I've found very confusing responses.

I use the same JPEG file (less than 1K) here but get different results. Here are my testing steps:

Test 1. With interception **off** on Burp Suite, the image can be uploaded successfully and the response is expected.
[image]

Test 2. With interception **on** on Burp Suite, then forwarding the request **without** changing a word, the image is blocked for exceeding the MAX_FILE_SIZE, which is 1K.
[image]

So, my question is what Burp Suite has done on my request? Has it added more bytes to my request? How can I turn off it so that my request won't be affected?

Any ideas and answers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: While I can't answer the specific question on what Burp might or might not have done to your requests, it is easy for you to find out by yourself.

If you go into the HTTP History, check if the 'Edited' column has a check. If so, you can select the edited request in the request pane.

Comment: Possibly headers take up most of the space of the 1K which is allowed is my best guess..